# What is the formula for extracting the src from a calculated blendmode?

Tags: reverse, alpha, blending

How does one go about using a alpha blending formula to achieve the src rgb color from the resultant of the 2 blended together

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can just reorder the [alpha blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_blending#Alpha_blending) equation

> *Value* = (1 − *α*) · *Value*<sub>0</sub> + *α* · *Value*<sub>1</sub>

However, there are four variables in that equation: *α*, *Value*, *Value*<sub>0</sub> and *Value*<sub>1</sub>. You need to know three of them to calculate the fourth. So in your case you know the resulting color, *Value*, the *α* and maybe *Value*<sub>0</sub>. You can then reorder the equation as follows:

> −*α* · *Value*<sub>1</sub> = (1 − *α*) · *Value*<sub>0</sub> − *Value*
>
> *Value*<sub>1</sub> = (−1/*α*) · ((1 − *α*) · *Value*<sub>0</sub> − *Value*)

That is, if I understood you correctly. Which might not be the case. You might want to clarify your question.