# Extract heatmap on top of image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image like this one
[image: Heatmap with original image as background]
and the corresponding background image.
[image: Original image]

I am trying to extract the heatmap of the first image. My first approach was to mask every pixel that was not "equal enough" (thresholding the euclidean distance between every pixel), but the results were not good enough
[image: Mask]

Looks like a straightforward problem in image processing, but I lack experience. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any idea by which algorithm the heatmap was originally added onto the image?

Comment: This may be an answer to your quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139350/what-is-the-formula-for-extracting-the-src-from-a-calculated-blendmode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtaining the exact heat map is a highly **non-trivial** problem since the heat map was superimposed with **varying levels of transparency**.
This means that per pixel there are *two unknowns*:

1. The *heat map* itself and
2. *transparency* (they are linked but the exact mapping is unknown).

If a rough segmentation suffices, I suggest a simple thresholding via the color intensities. You can see that the stronger regions of the heatmap are surrounded by a strong, blue color:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVZK.png');

% Simple, manual color thresholding
mask1 = I(:,:,3) > 230 & I(:,:,1) < 30 & I(:,:,2) < 10;
```

Now we dilate the mask to close any holes in the blue heat map boundaries and fill the holes:

```
% Morphological processing
mask2 = imdilate(mask1, strel('disk',5,0));
mask2 = imfill(mask2, 'holes');
```

Finally, we can extract the heat map:

```
% Extract heat map
heat_map = I;
heat_map(~repmat(mask2,[1 1 3])) = 255;
imshow(heat_map)
```

Here is the [**Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiEW0.png)
[image]

*Edit:* If you have to process many similar images, it might be more robust to perform the segmentation in hsv space:

```
I_hsv = rgb2hsv(I);
mask1 = I_hsv(:,:,1) > 0.6 & I_hsv(:,:,1) < 0.7 & I_hsv(:,:,2) > 0.95 & I_hsv(:,:,3) > 0.9;
```

Comment: Thanks! 
By the way, could you explain more about segmentation in HSV space?

Comment: Sure. If you want to use the blue color for segmentation (as presented), then the threshold values in RGB space will depend on the illumination (brightness). In [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color space you can perform thresholding directly on the hue value with some constraints on saturation and value (shown in the last line of my answer).